# Curl doesn't login correctly

Tags: php, post, curl, authentication

I was going through some examples on the curl website. One example was to login to eBay using curl. I copied and pasted the code onto my own document to try it out, changed the username and password to mine, and it doesn't print out properly. The example is kind of long, so you can view the example here:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/ebay_login.html

I was trying to run this on my localhost, and it didn't show up. I thought maybe the links weren't updated, but even when I tried re-copying and pasting them into the code, it still failed.

What is going on here?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Showing us the sample code doesn't help much, since far too many things depend on the system YOU are running it on. is curl enabled? is php enabled? any errors messages? debugging/warnings enabled in php?

Comment: What Marc says. You can use `curl_error()` to find out what went wrong

Comment: It's an 2004 script?....maybe is not working anymore

Comment: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate. This is the error that shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script works for me. But I had to create file with cookies. I use firefox+firebug to connect to eBay and export cookies to file `ebay_cookies.txt`
Than I use this file in script:

```
$cookie_file_path = "ebay_cookies.txt";
```

Normally you have to use curl to connect to main page, get **current** cookies and use it to connect to all other pages. Your script have to behave like human ;)

Comment: Isn't that what curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path) and curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path) are supposed to do? I made a cookie file, called it cookies.txt, and had it in the same directory as my script.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` "manage" cookies (read/write to $cookie_file_path). I didn't watch code before, I run script and it shows me ebay page with message "your browser not manage cookies" so I use firebug to create not empty cookies file. But now I watch script and I see: first curl gets cookies, second use POST to login. I try script again with empty cookies file (and of course I forgot to set write privilage for all users) and after second run it works again. Do you have any problem with this script ?

Comment: My problem is that it isn't writing to my cookie file. It is always blank every time I check it

Comment: I got the same problem before I set write privilage to all users - on linux: `chmod a+rw cookies.txt`